# Is there anyway set layout text in cpp file?

Tags: blackberry-10

I'm first to BlackBerry Native developing, and I'm now getting trouble with basic things in Cascades.

Is there anyway setting layout text or priority from cpp file??

For example, Android SDK has `findViewById()` method. Is there anything similar with this in BlackBerry SDK?

Comment: May this link help you http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/dev/integrating_cpp_qml/#injectingcobjectsintoqml

Comment: @Ankur That looks what I exactly wanted! Thank you!